# Items drawn with javascript not visible after history.go(-1)

Tags: javascript, caching, browser-history, cytoscape.js, history.js

I am using `socket.io` to communicate between server and client and then draw things with `cytoscape.js` in javascript.

For instance, I use

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function () {
  socket.emit('create new');
}
```

to tell the server to create a new item. From the server, I tell the client to draw it on the page

```
socket.on('new object', function (data) {
  // draw with cytoscape
  cy.add(data); // add data object to cytoscape elements
});
```

It works, but the problem is that if I click some link on the page to go to another page, and then return by using the browsers back button (`history.go(-1)`), the elements I have drawn using javascript is not present any longer.

I have to reload the page, to get the data to show.

At first I thought it was a cache problem, but I am not using cache or anything else, so I am suspecting that it is a problem with either `cytoscape.js` or `socket.io`. It might be that `cytoscape.js` doesn't save what has been drawn (somewhere?) on the client.

Comment: You probably want to have a read of this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: Pete's right.  You'll have to reinit the state of your app whenever you change the address with the history API